# Proving or disproving vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm supposed to prove or disprove that a group with the following conditions is a vector space:

$\mathbb F=R, V=\mathbb R_{>0}=\{x\in\mathbb R|x>0\}$

With the following operations:

$\forall v_1,v_2\in V|v_1\boxplus v_2=v_1\cdot v_2$

$\forall v\in V,\alpha\in \mathbb R|\alpha\boxdot v=v^\alpha$

I'm given the hint that the zero element of V is not zero.

While I'm not sure what how the hint can help me, nor am I sure that I did this correctly, I created a counter-proof as follows:

According to rules of vector spaces:

$(a+b)\cdot v=a\cdot v+b\cdot v$

I plug in the given operations as such:

$\alpha\boxdot v=v^\alpha \rightarrow v^{a+b}\ne v^a+v^b$

I am not sure If this is correct (EDIT: this is wrong) or even in the right direction. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: but $+$ is not $+$ either, so instead of $v^a+v^b$ you should have $v^a\cdot v^b$ (that is, use the $\boxplus$ as defined, rather than $+$). If you get this, you will get the rest of it too.

Comment: Ok That makes sense, however, I am not sure where to go now lol

Comment: If $v$ is a vector and $\alpha$ is a scalar, what does $v^\alpha$ mean?

Comment: vector $v$ times itself $\alpha$ times, like any other time you take something to the power of something else

Comment: If $z$ is the zero element of $V$, it must have the property that $z\boxplus v=v$ for all $v$. That is, $z\cdot v=v$. Solve for $z$.

Comment: @Mirko any idea how the 0 thing plays in to the proof?

Comment: yes, I just gave you a hint re the 0 element, see above

Comment: You can't multiply a vector by itself.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern yes, you can, since these "vectors" are reals, as described in the statement. So you use the usual operations of the reals to define the vector operations in the vector space.

Comment: So the problem, more briefly, is "prove the real positive real numbers are a vector space under multiplication and exponentiation"?

Comment: @Mirko so $Z=1$ from what I understand, but I don't see how that helps me. couldn't I prove that $1v=v^1=v$ without this?

Comment: It looks like $1$ is at the same time the additive identity, $1\boxplus v=1\cdot v=v$, and the multiplicative identity, $1\boxdot v=v^1=v$.